# can we consider an "ip" address as a string using fread and fwrite in python?

Tags: python, csv

I have a server log in csv format. It has lot of IP addresses. I am writing a code that checks each line to see if it has the required IP and copy the entire line to a new file if the IP was matched. This process need to be done for multiple IP addresses. How can i get the entire line with matched ip's in python?

```
fread = open("test1.csv","r")
fwrite = open("test2.csv", 'a')
strings = ['1.186.120.149', '1.186.8.1', '1.187.14.3', '99.253.12.8']
for line in fread:
    if any(s in line for s in strings):
        fwrite.write(line + "")
fwrite.close()
fread.close()
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Is the IP address in `test1.csv` to be compared against those in `strings` in a specific column?

Comment: That looks ok to me. Does it not work? What output do you get?

Comment: can you copy paste some lines of  the csv content? (csv is ascii, open it in a text editor, not excel or spreadsheet program)

Comment: Do you only want IP address in a single cell (`blah,blah,1.187.14.3,blah`) or part of the cell (`blah,blah,this is 1.187.14.3 address,blah`)?

Comment: Your subject line is confusing... there are no `fread` or `fwrite` functions in python. Those are just variable names you happened to use. _"can we consider an “ip” address as a string in a file?"_ might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

the code looks fine to me.

tip: open python console, and try it with simpel code first (without read and write, so you know where the problem is:

```
strings = ['1.186.120.149', '1.186.8.1', '1.187.14.3', '99.253.12.8']
lines =['Whatever without the ip','1.186.8.1 logged on']
for line in lines:
    if any(s in line for s in strings):
        line
```

I have the correct output for this small test code:

```
>>> strings = ['1.186.120.149', '1.186.8.1', '1.187.14.3', '99.253.12.8']
>>> lines =['baldie bla','1.186.8.1 logged on']
>>> for line in lines:
...    if any(s in line for s in strings):
...        line
... 
'1.186.8.1 logged on'
>>>
```

and use this:

```
with open(filenamepath, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
```

this will close automatically when exit the with ....

even better, use unit testing... but I assume that's not in your skills (but something to look in to in an early stage, saves a lot of time) TDD (test driven development)

and use pdb (python debugger)

put this in the code:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

and you can debug!

you can type the variables to see what they are... and with n to next line, or q for quit, s for stepping into another funstion and so on.

Answer (score 0):

CSV's are text files, so yes, you can consider IP addresses as a string. You demonstrate dotted IPv4 address notation which is a common way presenting IP addresses but its not the only way possible. Assuming your CSV is using dotted notation, then your only problem is differentiating between similar addresses such as `1.2.3.4` verses `11.2.3.4`.

The following code uses regular expressions to find the full IPv4 addresses in a line then uses `set` logic to identify matches.

```
import re

ip4_addr_re = re.compile(r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+')

strings = ['1.186.120.149', '1.186.8.1', '1.187.14.3', '99.253.12.8']
ip4_set = set(strings)

with open("test1.csv","r") as fread, open("test2.csv", 'a') as fwrite:
    for line in fread:
        if not ip4_set.isdisjoint(set(ip4_addr_re.findall(line))):
            fwrite.write(line)
```